# utility function in lodash/javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to look out for an utility function in Lodash/JavaScript that takes the JavaScript object element in the array as input and outputs the duplicated elements in an array, basically my requirement is like below,

```
input = 
{'first': 'Tom', 'last': 'Hanks', 'array': [1,2,3]};

output = 
[{first:’Tom’, 'array':[1], ‘last’: ‘Hanks’}, {first:’ Tom’, 'array':[2], ‘last’: ‘Hanks’}, {first:’ Tom’, 'array':[3], ‘last’: ‘Hanks’}];
```

I tried to look into Lodash manual, but could not find any function that performs this operation. Can someone let me know if we have any utility function similar to my expectation?

I can write a piece of javascript code but I am looking out for an efficient way.

Comment: your `input` and `output` arrays do not contain valid objects, are you sure that this is the data structure that you are starting from?

Comment: you input is  not valid.
{first:’Tom’, [1,2,3], ‘last’: ‘Hanks’} should be a valid object.

Comment: thanks Nobita and PPB, I have edited my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map), [at()](https://lodash.com/docs#at), and [defaults()](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults) to get what you need:

```
_.map(input.array, function(item, index, coll) {
    return _.defaults({ array: _.at(coll, index) }, input);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[_.uniq](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) should do what you want.

Comment: I see _.uniq returns the list of unique items in the array and it wont work my scenario..

Comment: You can create the new array and then wipe the equal items from the old array.